# Modal logic question about possibility (axiom?)

Tags: modal-logic

I'm not sure if 
PN(A) implies N(A)
is an axiom or if it follows from the definition of P(possibility).

Comment: Welcome to philosophy SE!  I urge you to visit the tour:    And the Help Center: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help  It would  be useful for you to read "how to ask a good question" https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask, as this question lacks context, or any indication of the research you have done to answer it yourself either on your own or by looking for in prior Philosophy SE questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using P to represent the 'possibly' operator, which is more commonly represented by ◊ or M, and N to represent the 'necessarily' operator, which is more commonly represented by ◻ or L, then the proposition

◊ ◻ A → ◻ A

is a theorem of system S5 of modal logic. It is derivable as follows:

> 1. ◊ A → ◻ ◊ A      ........ axiom 5
> 2. ◊ ¬A → ◻ ◊ ¬A      ........ from 1 by substitution of ¬A/A
> 3. ¬ ◻ A → ¬ ◊ ◻ A   ...... from 2 using the equivalences of ◻ to ¬◊¬ and ◊ to ¬◻¬
> 4. ◊ ◻ A → ◻ A       ...... from 3 by contraposition